# Como melhorar a velocidade do TestCase no Django?

Tags: postgresql, desempenho, django, testcase

Estou rodando um teste no Django com apenas duas querys e no cronômetro está levando **1 min e 10 segundos** para finalizar o teste. Existe alguma configuração que possa ajustar para acelerar os testes?

Atualmente estou usando [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) no banco de dados do projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui melhorar o desempenho alterando o banco para sqlite3 e direcionando o teste para um app específico:

**settings.py** (ao final do arquivo):

```
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'test_db'
    }
```

**terminal:**

```
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests
```

Ao rodar o teste o tempo caiu para **5 segundos**.